# Nested folder structure with multiple git repos: submodules, subtrees or .gitignore?

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore, git-subtree

I have set up a set of large Repositories (interlinked HTML-Documentation) and have these requirements:

1. since they are large, i needed to split them up into multiple Repos
2. Repos need to be checked out into a fixed Folder structure so the relative Links work
3. users should be able to pick and check out individual repos
4. all Repos have a simple, linear history with usually only 'main' branch
5. The actual Version of each repo is not critical (unlike with Code), as long as the files are not moved (which is forbidden, users are asked to leave a forwarding tombstone)
6. List item

This is what I have tried:

1. nested submodules: these quickly created conflicts with me, because they track the individual version of each sub-repo which is different in each clone. (Sub-question: are these conflicts 'normal'? Does this ever work in a distributed environment where submodules constantly change or it it a bad idea to use submodules?)
   We have started to no longer check in the upper/downstream Repos to avoid conflicts, but one result is that it is always 'dirty'
2. nested repositories in Folders marked as .gitignore: This seems to works and is sufficient, because the versions between individual repos are not critical. I wonder though if this is a good practice. Mind that cloning all sub-repos is a hassle, but individual users must be able to pick sub-sections. I think about checking in scripts to clone and pull whole sub-directories of repos, but is there maybe a better way?
3. subtrees: AFAIK these track the full history of the nested repos within the upper/root repo, which would be way too huge. Can someone comment on this?

Comment: Not an answer, but out of curiosity: how large is all of that documentation? I'm surprised that simple HTML documentation would become prohibitively large.

Comment: Hi, it is Product and Marketing material, past, present and future with multi-media content interspersed. We try to structure the repo by years, so a user can choose which year to download. Every year 3GB are added.

Comment: Hmmm are you sure you want to keep a history of those multimedia files? In general it makes sense to keep track of text files (like code) since their history is super relevant, and you can see when bugs were added etc. But for multimedia files, the diffs from commit to commit won't contain relevant info. If  I were you, I would try as much as possible to keep anything non-text based out of git. Of course I don't have the complete context here but that's just my 2 cents :)